# Como saber cuando cuando la peticion al servidor ha terminado con Angular2 y Firebase

Tags: firebase, angularjs-2.0, typescript

Estoy usando [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) para comunicarme con el backend Firebase de Google. Este es el código:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item in items | async">
      {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `,
})
class AppComponent {
  items: Observable<any>;
  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.items = af.database.list('/items');
  }
}
```

La instruccion `af.database.list('items')` se toma unos segundos en extraer la información desde Firebase.

¿Hay alguna forma de saber en que momento se termina de extraer la información?

Si supiera cuando la información ha llegado puedo mostrar una "barra de carga" hasta que los datos lleguen.

Gracias!

Comment: Creo que tienes un error en tu código, en lugar de `this.item = af.database.list('/items');` debería ser `this.items = ...`

Comment: Si, hay un error. Ya he actualizado el código, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te devuelve `af.database.list('/items')` es una clase llamada [FirebaseListObservable](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md#firebaselistobservable) que hereda de [RxJS Observable](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md) por lo que todos los métodos de los observables están disponibles para usarse.

La forma más simple es iniciando con la barra de progreso activa y quitarla cuando te llega cualquier cosa. Para esto puedes usar el metodo `subscribe`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';
// Implementa la barra de progreso como un componente
import {ProgressBar} from 'myprogressbar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: `
  <ProgressBar [active]="loading" />
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item in items | async">
      {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `,
  directives: [ProgressBar]
})
class AppComponent {
  item: Observable<any>;
  loading: boolean;
  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.items = af.database.list('/items');

    this.items.subscribe(data => {
        this.loading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Lo voy a probar. Gracias!

Comment: Gracias @devconcept, funciona genial.